# no me cargan los estilos css a jsp

Tags: css, jsp

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Saludos, no entiendo que problema hay en la ruta para acceder al archivo css y dar estilos a mi jsp. sabran si me estoy saltando algo? no tiene sentido segir elaborando el proyecto si no resuelvo esto primero. Es la primera vez que intento usar css en un archivo jsp por eso no se si este proceso sea diferente a como se hace en HTML o en Java

Comment: Probaste href="CSS/Estilos.css"?

Comment: tal ves te pueda ayudar esta respuesta https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7382607/how-to-load-css-file-into-jsp/7382781
saludos

Comment: si CSS/Estilos.css  /CSS/Estilos.css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agrega **type**.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="CSS/Estilos.css"/>
```

Comment: gracias por tu interes, lo acabo de probar y sigue sin cargar los estilos, repito es primera ves que intento cargar css a un jsp nc si aparte de usar el link haga  falta hacer otra cosa o moverlo de carpeta tal ves. la verdad es q nc.

Answer (score 0):

¿Has probado a poner rutas absolutas?

```
< link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/tuaplicacion/CSS/estilos.css"/>
```

Ten una cosa en cuenta, para todas las paginas la ruta "css/estilos.css" no es la misma, porque depende de la jerarquía de paginas y carpetas que tengas, el css para ellos estará en un sitio o en otro.

La mejor forma es usar una ruta completa en vez de una relativa, yo usaría algo tipo http://mipaginaweb.com/css/estilos.css y se lo agregas como ruta total y no relativa.

Answer (score 0):

gracias a todos por la ayuda, a la final la ruta era simple CSS/Estilos.css solo que tenia un problema de nombres con las clases del css (UPS) y solo pensaba que el error debia de ser algo diferente ya que nunca habia usado css en jsp, me centre desde el principio a q el error provenía de alguna configuracion o que debia de moverla de carpeta.

Comment: Tengo el mismo problema, que problema de nombres era el que tenias? comprobé la ruta y aún no me cargan los estilos.